# Как приостановить или задать паузу, пока не будет выполнен другой поток?

Tags: java, android, json, многопоточность

Нужно, чтобы приложение не отвечало до тех пор, пока созданный поток недовыполнит свою задачу. Ну например:

```
class Zapis implements Runnable {

    long zapis;

    Zapis(long zapis) {
        this.zapis = zapis;
    }

    public void run() {
        // Тут файл записывает информацию в json файл.
    }
}
```

И нужно, чтобы пока будет записывать этот поток, приложение не отвечало и не давало возможности переходить на другие Фрагменты.

Comment: Забыл написать, что после в коде 
Zapis p = new Zapis(143);  //создаю 

new Thread(p).start(); и после запускаю этот самый поток.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть стандартный метод `Thread.join()`

Подробный разбор `join()` [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164487/)

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread trity = new Thread(p);
trity.start();
while (trity.isAlive()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вот как-то так получилось.

Comment: не знаю как в android, но в java не стоит так писать.